# Python - Print items from a dict sorted by value

Tags: sorting, python-3.x, dictionary, key-value

Here is a dict of pets and how many of them.

```
{"Birds" : 2, "Cats" : 3, "Dogs" : 4}
```

I want to print the items sorted by largest number of the same pet to the smallest number of the same pet, or vice versa.

Desired output:

```
('Dogs', 4)
('Cats', 3)
('Birds', 2)
```

And

```
('Birds', 2)
('Cats', 3)
('Dogs', 4)
```

How could this be done?

I do not want to import anything.

Answer (score 1):

with lambda expression `x[1]` stands for values, `x[0]` for keys in key-value pair from a dictionary.

```
sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True) 
sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])
```

without lambda expr, operator.itemgetter does the same thing:

```
from operator import itemgetter

sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the built-in `sorted` function with a special ranking function and a `reverse=True` argument:

```
for item in sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
    print(item)
```

A key of `lambda x: -x[1]` should also work (without reverse argument).

Answer (score 0):

For purposes of understanding from a beginners point of view sometimes it is better to write more code to achieve this.
As dictionaries cannot be sorted, you can take each key and value pair and return a list with a simple function.

```
mydict = {"Birds" : 2, "Cats" : 3, "Dogs" : 4}
def sortDict(dictionary):
    sorted_values = sorted(dictionary.values())
    sorted_keys = sorted(dictionary.keys())
    #sorted_values.reverse()
    #sorted_keys.reverse()
    for key, value in zip(sorted_keys, sorted_values):
        print(key, value)
sortDict(mydict)
```

Simply remove the `#` characters to reverse the result.